# Error in Databricks delta live table pipeline while trying to run a simple create table query

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

```
%sql
CREATE LIVE TABLE phonenumbers_clean(
  CONSTRAINT valid_phone_present EXPECT (valid_phone_number IS NOT NULL)
)
COMMENT "Clean Phone Numbers."
AS 
SELECT 
phone_number_validation_udf(Phone_Numbers) as valid_phone_number 
FROM hive_metastore.abc.phonenumbers
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> com.databricks.pipelines.execution.core.ExecutionFailedException: You attempted to update an empty pipeline. This error usually means no tables were discovered in your specified source code. Please verify that your source code includes table definitions.
> What am i missing. Its as simple as can be.

*Note phone_number_validation_udf is an udf already defined. hive_metastore.abc.phonenumbers is just a table with phone numbers.

your help is extremely appreciated.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpAbH.png)
[Notebook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6N8H.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Magic commands, such as %py, %sql, and %run, are not supported, with the exception of %pip within a Python notebook. Cells containing magic commands are ignored.**

You have a cell with the magic command `%sql`, which is ignored and raises below error because the DLT pipeline needs at least one table as output.

**The com.databricks.pipelines.execution.core.ExecutionFailedException occurs when you attempt to update an empty pipeline. This error usually indicates that no tables were discovered in your specified source code. Please verify that your source code includes table definitions.**

You need to either use a notebook with pure SQL or pure Python. Remove `%sql` and convert the notebook to SQL.

[image]

Comment: i am using as my notebook.  Please find my screenshot. I dont know why this would not work. When i remove the %sql it automatically converts the notebook to python. Its quite the pickle here.

Comment: I have provided screenshot make notebook language to sql. Click on drop down of top left corner er you can select sql and remove  %sql

Comment: Also tried with this python code and get the same error

Comment: `from delta.tables import DeltaTable

def phonenumbers_clean():
    # create Delta table
    delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "path/to/delta/table")
    
    # run query
    df = spark.table("hive_metastore.tc_test_functions.phonenumbers")
    cleaned_df = df.selectExpr("phone_number_validation_udf(Phone_Numbers) as phonenumbers_cleaned")
    
    # write results to Delta table
    delta_table.alias("original_data").\
        merge(cleaned_df.alias("new_data"), "original_data.Phone_Numbers = new_data.Phone_Numbers").\
        whenNotMatchedInsertAll().\
        execute()`

Comment: Syntax is incorrect, refer this doc for python `https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/tutorial-python.html` and for sql  `https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/tutorial-sql.html`

Comment: Your sql code is correct just change the notebook language to sql.

Comment: Are you using databricks right?

Comment: I fixed the problem differently

`
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
tab = spark.sql("SELECT Phone_Numbers,phone_number_validation_py(Phone_Numbers) as cleaned_phone_numbers  FROM hive_metastore.abc.phonenumbers")

@dlt.table(
  comment="This is raw phonenumber table "
)
def phonenumberscleaned():
    return tab
`

Comment: Yeah this is what pure python for dlt  I am trying to say.

Comment: Either you use sql or python. Not both in single notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved this issue:

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
tab = spark.sql("SELECT Phone_Numbers,phone_number_validation_py(Phone_Numbers) as cleaned_phone_numbers  FROM hive_metastore.abc.phonenumbers")

@dlt.table(
  comment="This is raw phonenumber table "
)
def phonenumberscleaned():
    return tab
```